# How to generate/export a custom format of CSV file?

Tags: magento2, csv, magento-2.1.1

I hope some one can help me.

Now, I want to generate a csv file of my sales order, but I think existing magento 2 csv format is not fulfill my expectation.
Could anyone can help me how to generate the below CSV file format through magento 2 admin export function.

Thanks!

The below image is my expect CSV data format result: 
[image]